# MySQL Workbench "OLD" syntax changed?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I had a trigger set in MySQL workbench that used to accomplish what I wanted. Recently, my workplace updated MySQL workbench to version 6.3.10 across all computers and the triggers were dropped during the update for some reason.

Basically, the trigger should update a column with the current date when a different column is changed. This was previously achieved by using the following syntax:

```
if (NEW.colname <> OLD.colname or (OLD.colname is null && NEW.colname is not null)) 
then 
set NEW.othercolname = current_date()
```

The issue is when I try to recreate the same trigger in the new MySQL version and apply it, I am met with the error:

```
ERROR 1363: There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger
```

It seems to me that MySQL is looking for a row named OLD, which does not exist; however, this syntax used to work in previous versions for the intended result. Can anyone suggest an alternative syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you sure you're creating the trigger on `UPDATE` and not `INSERT`?

Comment: @duskwuff Thank you so much. The error persisted because I accidentally typed the code into ```before insert``` instead of ```before update```. I would delete this post, but it will not let me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ERROR 1363: There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger
> ```

You've got MySQL Workbench set to create an INSERT trigger. As the error message says, there's no `OLD` row in an INSERT trigger.

What you want is an UPDATE trigger.

Comment: Yep! Exactly right. Sorry for the wasteful post, I should've realized this earlier. Long day.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the error message comes from mysql, not from mysql workbench, so mysql workbench's version is irrelevant here.

Secondly, the error message is pretty clear: you are trying to refer to the `OLD` row in an insert trigger. This is obviously impossible, since there is no old row when you insert a new one.

You need to change either the trigger to catch an update event or change the trigger logic.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I overlooked this. I was entering this trigger on ```insert``` and not ```update```. Long day and didn't even realize.